# Validating WMD Editor content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, wmd-editor

I want to validate (as a RequiredField) the WMD Editor content

```
<div class="wmd-panel">
    <div id="wmd-editor">
        <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
            <textarea id="wmd-input" name="Body" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(post => post.Body) %>
        </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; height: 24px;" class="fr"> </div>
    <div id="wmd-preview"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using its name as `Body` to be bound to the Linq-to-Sql Column Body. I want the validation to be enabled at client-side so that no data will be sent to the server if the model has an issue.

As you can see, I tried to put `Html.ValidationMessageFor(post => post.Body)` but I am still able to send a `Post` request without filling the `Body` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use HTML helpers to generate the `textarea` if you want client validation to work:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(post => post.Body, 2, 50, new { id = "wmd-input" }) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(post => post.Body) %>
```

This will emit the proper HTML5 `data-*` attributes on the textarea that will allow for client validation to work using the `jquery.validate` plugin.